# Not able to figure out why django can't reverse the URL

Tags: python, django

## error

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for ''tazasabzii.tazasabzi.views.gallery'' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('tazasabzii.tazasabzi',

    (r'^tazasabzi/gallery/$', 'views.gallery'),
```

## views.py

```
def gallery(request):
    z = {'title':'TazaSabzi.com',
         'heading':'TazaSabzi.com',
         'viewName':'gallery',}
    fruits = Sabji.objects.filter(kind__contains="fruit")
    sfruits = Sabji.objects.filter(kind__contains="special fruit")
    svegetables = Sabji.objects.filter(kind__contains="special vegetable")
    vegetables = Sabji.objects.filter(kind__contains="vegetable")
    soffers = Sabji.objects.filter(kind__contains="special offer")
    saari_sabzi = {'fruits':fruits,
                                            'vegetables':vegetables,
                                            'special fruits':sfruits,
                                            'special vegetables':svegetables,
                                            'special offers':soffers,}
    return render_to_response('gallery.html',{'tz':z,
                                              'saari_sabzi':saari_sabzi.iteritems(),},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## error

```
154     <a target="_blank" href="{% url 'tazasabzii.tazasabzi.views.gallery' %}">
155     <div class="gallery button" style="width:100px;">
156     <div style="color:white; margin-top:5px;">Gallery</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `<a target="_blank" href="{% url 'appname.views.gallery' %}">`

OR

Use [named URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns)

OR

probably you didn't include app urls in main url_conf

Comment: Read the docs for [`url tag`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url).

Comment: yea i have tried all possible combinations , its not working at all , same error again and again

Comment: Remove the `'` around the view name. Another common error is a missing \__init__.py file in the views dir...